git tag mixup - how to recover?
I have a Python project on GitHub that uses reathedocs.io for the documentation. I use  setuptools_scm to create versioning information from the git tags automatically. Recently, the readthedocs pipeline started to fail. The problem seems related to some mixup with the git tags. The readthedocs pipeline executes the following:
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/uliw/esbmtk.git .
git fetch origin --force --prune --prune-tags --depth 50 refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

if I run this locally in an empty environment the last command results in
From https://github.com/uliw/esbmtk
 * [new tag]         v.0.12.0.8 -> v.0.12.0.8

However
git describe --all
tags/0.12.0.25

shows the expected 0.12.0.25 version
I am fairly new to git, so any guidance on what is happening here (and how to resolve this) is much appreciated

You are mixing tags with names in different formats, including "{VERSION}", "v{VERSION}", and "v.{VERSION}". This probably has something to do with your issue.

I noticed. Can I simply delete the "v.0.12.0.8" tag? From my reading in other posts, this may have side effects?

@Uliw git push -d origin <TAG NAME> won't break the history

it was indeed as sinmple as removing the offending tag with
git push -d origin v.0.12.0.8


See Git Documentation:

With --all, the command can use branch heads as references, so the output shows the reference path as well.

Just check and replace 'tags/' to ''.
